# How to add the dots inside the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have this code

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
% Default actions for each node
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, shape=circle];
% Define and draw five nodes
\node (v0) at (4:0) {$v_0$};
\node (v1) at (0:4) {$v_1$};
%\node (v2) at (8:9) {$v_2$};
%\node (v3) at (30:8) {$v_3$};
%\node (v4) at (8:10) {$v_4$};
% Draw radial edges
\draw (v0) -- (v1) ;
%(v0) -- (v2)
%(v0) -- (v3) (v0) -- (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got the output of the above code as 
[image]

I want to add dots inside each node

[image]

Is it possible to get the output as shown here?
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: This remain me on symbols from the Petri net (see ilustration on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) . For it exist library for TikZ. See tutorial *3 Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen* in TikZ & PGF manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tikzstyle` is deprecated. You can use a `path picture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={draw, shape=circle,minimum size=2em,
path picture={\fill (20:0.5em) circle[radius=1.5pt]
 (140:0.5em) circle[radius=1.5pt]  (260:0.5em) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}}]
\node[circ,label=below:$v_0$] (v0) at (0,0) {};
\node[circ,label=below:$v_1$] (v1) at (0:4) {};
\draw (v0) -- (v1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a variable number of dots...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={draw, shape=circle,minimum size=2em,
path picture={\foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
{\fill ({20+360*(\X-1)/#1}:0.5em) circle[radius=0.5pt];}
}},circ/.default=3]
\path 
(-135:3) node[circ=1,label=below:$v_0$] (v0) {}
(-45:3) node[circ=2,label=below:$v_1$] (v1) {}
(45:3) node[circ=3,label=above:$v_2$] (v2) {}
(135:3) node[circ=3,label=above:$v_3$] (v3){}
;
\draw (v0) -- (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you reduce the size of the dots

Comment: @Math_Freak The size of the circle nodes is controlled by `minimum size=2em` and the sizes of the dots by `radius=1.5pt`.

Comment: Oh okay, i made it 0.5 and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Also, how to make the number of dots different in each node, is it possble?

Comment: @Math_Freak Did you try to understand the meaning of the above code?

Comment: @BlackMild; yes, actually i am a beginner just started with tikz, so i am not so comfortable